# Object not Renderer in OpenGL ES Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am using the opengGl Es 2 in android to render the 3D object. But I am facing the problem that Object does not render means nothing is drawn on the screen.

```
public void draw(GL10 gl) 
{
    gl.glColor4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    for(int i=0; i<parts.size(); i++)
    {
        TDModelPart t=parts.get(i);
        gl.glNormalPointer(GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, t.getNormalBuffer());
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES,t.getFacesCount(),GL10.GL_FLOAT,t.getFaceBuffer());
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    }
}

public class TDModelPart   
    {
    Vector<Float> faces;
    Vector<Float> vtPointer;
    Vector<Float> vnPointer;
    Material material;
    private FloatBuffer normalBuffer;
    FloatBuffer faceBuffer;

    public TDModelPart(Vector<Float> faces, Vector<Float> vtPointer, Vector<Float> vnPointer, Material material, Vector<Float> vn) 
    {
        super();
        this.faces = faces;
        this.vtPointer = vtPointer;
        this.vnPointer = vnPointer;
        this.material = material;

        ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vnPointer.size() * 4*3);
        byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        normalBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
        for(int i=0; i<vnPointer.size(); i++){
            float x=vn.get((int) (vnPointer.get(i)*3));
            float y=vn.get((int) (vnPointer.get(i)*3+1));
            float z=vn.get((int) (vnPointer.get(i)*3+2));
            normalBuffer.put(x);
            normalBuffer.put(y);
            normalBuffer.put(z);
        }
        normalBuffer.position(0);

        ByteBuffer fBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(faces.size() * 4);
        fBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        faceBuffer = fBuf.asFloatBuffer();
        faceBuffer.put(toPrimitiveArrayS(faces));
        faceBuffer.position(0);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String str=new String();
        if(material!=null)
            str+="Material name:"+material.getName();
        else
            str+="Material not defined!";
        str+="\nNumber of faces:"+faces.size();
        str+="\nNumber of vnPointers:"+vnPointer.size();
        str+="\nNumber of vtPointers:"+vtPointer.size();
        return str;
    }

    public FloatBuffer getFaceBuffer()
    {
        return faceBuffer;
    }

    public FloatBuffer getNormalBuffer() 
    {
        return normalBuffer;
    }

    private static float[] toPrimitiveArrayS(Vector<Float> vector)      
    {
        float[] s;
        s=new float[vector.size()];
        for (int i=0; i<vector.size(); i++){
            s[i]=vector.get(i);
        }
        return s;
    }

    public int getFacesCount()
    {
        return faces.size();
    }

    public Material getMaterial()
    {
        return material;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you just make the same errors that have been pointed out to you in answers to your other questions. You are not likely to solve that problem if you're not reading any answers at all.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you set the data for the `glNormalPointer`, but you don't ever `glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)`. And then you also disable the vertex array (`glDisableCLientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)`) at the end of the for loop block, this means after drawing the first part, all following parts won't draw anything, since they have no vertex array enabled.

Likewise doesn't it fit that your normal data is specified per-part while your vertex data is specified only once for all parts. Maybe this is what you intended but it looks strange, since vertices (or rather positions) and normals (and all the other attributes) have to match, i.e. the draw commands drawing from those arrays use the same index for accessing all the enabled attribute arrays for a single vertex.

Comment: please write some code here so that it would help me..I am confused from your answer

Comment: @user2583144 That is hard to do if I don't know if that per-part normal data and per-mesh vertex data is really intended. But c'mon it's all in the answer, if you got that far, those two lines of code from the answer should be a piece of cake. Of course you didn't just copy and paste all this code from your question without understanding what it does. For a start just move that `glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)` after the loop and copy those `gl[En/Dis]ableClientState` things for the `GL_NORMAL_ARRAY`, too.

Comment: gl.glColor4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
  gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
  gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
  
  for(int i=0; i<parts.size(); i++){
   TDModelPart t=parts.get(i);
   gl.glNormalPointer(GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, t.getNormalBuffer());
   gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES,t.getFacesCount(),GL10.GL_FLOAT,t.getFaceBuffer());
  }
  gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
  gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);  I did like that but still nothing is drawn

Comment: @user2583144 Well, that vertex and normal data discrepancy looks much more fundamental and severe (but isn't likely to be fixed by just putting in some two lines of code either).

Comment: I am sharing the project on the dropbox. Please go through it. I could not recognize where is the problem trying since last 4 days and help me. https://www.dropbox.com/s/yo2iisxto14scjp/objLoader.rar

Comment: Please help me if you found any issue. I added the dropbox project link

Comment: Request : - Have you checked my code. Please help me if you find mistake in the code that not drawing anyting. I know this is not big issue for you.